# Cordova how to add a Plugin right?

Tags: android, cordova, plugins

I know the questions sounds a bit weired because it looks to be very simple. In my case I want to add the FCM Plugin (https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm) for Android in my cordova Project. As always I have these problem with adding a plugin to my app:

**Do I just have to enter this in my commandline?**
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm

Is that all, that a plugin is connected with my App? Dont I have to link my .html file to the .js file from the plugin? When I do so and go to my plugins folder and copy the .js from the FCM plugin to my www folder and include this to my .html:`<script type="text/javascript" src="FCMPlugin.js"></script>`. I got and error: 'require is not defined'. How to do it right a´nd get these plugins wokring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to command line or terminal navigate ti the director of your app and then paste `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm` and enter. that's all.